# What is the cost of injecting a service that is never used into a controller in grails application?

Tags: grails

What actually happens when we do `def someService`? Does the service code get linked to the controller code?

Answer (score 1):

Grails uses spring IOC, your controllers and services are managed as spring beans, when you define a service inside a controller, spring will inject the service inside the controller, code does not get linked in anyway, just reference to service will be set. Though its not a much expensive operation, you would not want to define service dependencies that are not used to keep the code clean

Answer (score 1):

I think under the hood it's the same process as Spring's `@Autowired` annotation, so you pay a bit of a performance penalty on start up but I don't think it's significant.

There's another stackoverflow question on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249458/is-springs-autowired-a-huge-performance-issue).

Answer (score 0):

> Does the service code get linked to the controller code?

That does not make sense.

Actually services in grails are singleton by default.So if you inject a Service by `def serviceName` it wont create a new service object but a reference to same old service object.
So its not expensive of course.

But if in a service there is a property static `session="prototype"` or some non-singleton like this.Then it is expensive .